# How to emphasize a part of a line in listing?

Tags: listings, emphasis

With the package `listing` I can use `emph=` to emphasize specific *identifiers* in the whole listing.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[style=towi, title=Functions,emph={add}]
void print(int arg) { /* ... */ }
int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
...
print(12);           // call function print
int sum = add(8, 4); // call function add
\end{lstlisting}
```

This will emphasize all instances of `add` in the listing.

But I want to emphasize only one specific instance, and not only the identifier, but want to choose freely, which part to emphasize, say `add(8, 4);`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve what you want, instead of adding `emph=`, define an `escapechar` and use the formatting of your `emphstyle` to emphasize that part of the line.

For example, let's suppose that you have

```
emphstyle=\underline
```

Then, defining

```
escapechar=ä
```

you can write

```
ä\underline{add(8, 4);}ä
```

to emphasize `add(8, 4);` and not the other occurrences of `add`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{%
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  emphstyle=\underline,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[title=Functions,emph={add}]
void print(int arg) { /* ... */ }
int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
...
print(12);           // call function print
int sum = add(8, 4); // call function add
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[title=Functions,escapechar=ä]
void print(int arg) { /* ... */ }
int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
...
print(12);           // call function print
int sum = ä\underline{add(8, 4);}ä // call function add
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]